# Проблемы автоматического форматирования и хоткеи eclipse

Tags: java, форматирование

Есть такая строка `System.out.print("123");`

В коде она выглядит так:

```
System.out.print(
"123"
);
```

Что нажать, чтобы она была бы в одну строку?

Далее...

Когда я нажимаю точку с запятой, то она не пишется в коде, что странно... Почему так? Может у вас есть идеи? У меня нет(

P.S. Когда в конце строки нажимаю на `";"`, то она должна срабатывать и строка форматируется, но почему-то этого не происходит, почему?

Тоже самое и с абзацем: когда нажимаешь `";" или "}"`, то тогда весь абзац должен быть отформатирован! Но этого не происходит.

Comment: Я ничего не понял из вопроса, но ctrl+shift+F отформатирует код в Eclipse.

Comment: @КириллМалышев я все написал, иначе не знаю, предложенная комбинация заменена была когда-то на "}" и ";", только вот ";"    больше не нажимаетс

Comment: Предложил правку к вопросу, надеюсь, угадал с его сутью

Comment: @glonval получается, угадал?

Comment: @KitScribe и что дальше? Я что-то решения не нашел(

Comment: @glonval так я про сам вопрос говорил. Он был непонятен. А решение ожидайте и проявляйте уважение к членам сообщества

Comment: @KitScribe ну лан, подожду)

Comment: IDEA Вам в помощь.